# It is allowed to have more APRS trackers with one callsign in Europe Union

Tags: legal, aprs, europe

I am interested if I can set up all my automatic APRS GPS trackers with one call sign in Austria (like in the US)? Are there any restrictions on usage?

Comment: My feeling is that EU is a bit too wide for a single answer.

Comment: ok, what about in Austria?

Comment: In Austria, you may set up all your APRS equipment with one call sign IMHO, but you are not allowed to (not for now) use a remote station in Austria. When transmitting, you have to stay at your transmitting location (or vehicle) - no automatic control without presence. You may get an official approval for remote stations if you inquire the "Fernmeldebüro" in Austria. Ham Radio repeater (relays) are only operated by clubs. Where do you live in Austria, in which federal state? - So I could support more information about "Fernmeldebüro", Tom, OE1TKT

Comment: Thanks for a help. I am working and living right now in Tirol, Innsbruck

Comment: @TomKuschel you should post that as an answer so that it can be accepted.